# Grails production WAR in tomcat6, hot re-deploment error: call 'refresh' before accessing beans via the ApplicationContext

Tags: deployment, grails, refresh, tomcat6, war

I have a grails WAR that works in production in tomcat6, but when I go to redeploy the WAR, I overwrite the WAR files. The app reloads and I can load the front page (static page) but then when I try go to any other page I get this warning.

```
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.taglib.exceptions.GrailsTagException: Error executing tag <g:render>: Error creating bean with name 'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.taglib.ApplicationTagLib': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: BeanFactory not initialized or already closed - call 'refresh' before accessing beans via the ApplicationContext at /WEB-INF/grails-app/views/layouts/baseContainer.gsp:28

        at gsp_app_layoutsbaseContainerMapFb_gsp$_run_closure2.doCall(gsp_app_layoutsbaseContainer_gsp.groovy:42)

        at gsp_app_layoutsbaseContainerMapFb_gsp$_run_closure2.doCall(gsp_app_layoutsbaseContainer_gsp.groovy)

        at gsp_app_layoutsbaseContainerMapFb_gsp.run(gsp_app_layoutsbaseContainerMa_gsp.groovy:49)

        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.taglib.ApplicationTagLib': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: BeanFactory not initialized or already closed - call 'refresh' before accessing beans via the ApplicationContext

        at gsp_app_templates_facebookConnect_gsp.run(gsp_app_templates_facebookConnect_gsp.groovy:23)

        ... 4 more

    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: BeanFactory not initialized or already closed - call 'refresh' before accessing beans via the ApplicationContext
```

What am I don't wrong? How can I call this so called "refresh"?

Whats the best way to hot redeploy WAR's on tomcat?

Answer (score 2):

We'll probably not be able to resolve this at Stackoverflow. I hope you'll grade my support attempt, though, if you cannot find better information.

First, the Grails documentation suggests to [restart Tomcat](http://www.grails.org/Deployment#Tomcat) after (re-)deployment. But this shouldn't be necessary in most cases.

When Tomcat reloads the web application, a Grails `ServletContextListener` gets informed about that event and creates (should create) the Grails/Spring `ApplicationContext` that wires all the application's Spring beans (by using the aforementioned `refresh(..)` method, BTW). This goes wrong in your case.

Normally, after hot-deployment, you'll just have to wait a while until the `ApplicationContext` is completely available, but it should be after some time, finally. In between these two states, your error would be normal. [Spring is working on the problem](https://jira.springframework.org/browse/SPR-3051?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Aall-tabpanel#issue-tabs) (for quite some time now) to make Spring's `DispatcherServlet` wait for the second state even when requests come in before that. So this is considered an *improvement*, not a bug.

As for the deployment process to Tomcat itself, see the [Tomcat documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/deployer-howto.html#Deploying_on_a_running_Tomcat_server). By default, hot-deployment should be as easy as overwriting an existing WAR file and letting Tomcat unpack it, but that can be customized on the `<Host>` tag in *conf/server.xml*.

Other ideas:

- I guess you did wait long enough after re-deployment to make sure the error doesn't occur for a limited time, only.
- You could post the complete stacktrace.
- In the *web.xml* file of your WAR, are there any `<listener>`s or `<filter>`s that do not belong to the namespace `org.codehaus...`?
- Do you use any special plugins, versions, specifications?
- If you've setup a *virtual host* in Tomcat, have some look at the `autoDeploy` and `unpackWAR` settings.

Comment: Reloaded the WAR, waited 15 minutes with no requests and still the exact same error, Regarding the web.xml namespaces
they're two other mentions of the springSecurityFilterChain and the charEncodingFilter, on the org.springframework.filter

the stack pretty much ends there as I gave it,  seems to be the taglib beans

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.taglib.ValidationTagLib

Comment: Regarding plugins, Recaptcha, tomcat, mail, spring security, quartz and cookie,  would quartz have any affect?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't tell. - I can see two strategies to debug the issue: 1. Refine the logging output; logs: $CATALINA_HOME/logs/*, $CATALINA_HOME/stacktrace.log, log as set in your log4j configuration. - 2. Starting with a "pure" Grails application, somewhere in your app there is software / configuration that makes a difference regarding this issue. - After all, you could just restart Tomcat; depending on the webapps, this could cost less than half a minute.